# My Python set-up is too complicated, and I don't understand it. Currently my Python is unusable. Advice would be welcome

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

Here is a sequence of my commands, and my system's response. This shows that I do not know how to access numpy with my current (very confusing) Python setup. It was recently working, but then I changed something, but can't remember what.

I run MacOs 10.14.6 on a Macbook Pro.

```
dbae$ which $SHELL
/bin/bash

dbae$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

dbae$ echo $PATH
/Users/dbae/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/universal-darwin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/dbae/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:

dbae$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

dbae$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python

dbae$ /opt/local/bin/python --version
Python 3.8.3

dbae$ which pip
/opt/local/bin/pip

dbae$ /opt/local/bin/pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

dbae$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/84/23ed6a1796480a6f1a2d38f2802901d078266bda38388954d01d3f2e821d/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.3.1:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

dbae$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.17.4)
```

Comment: You can be excused for finding this difficult. It's a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you kind of screwed your pip setup. Start with the beginning :

```
$ python -m pip list
```

What is returned by this command ?

I would suggest you start using virtual environment (venv). It is much easier to handle module dependency issues in the future.

```
$ python -m venv /path/to/env
$ source /path/to/env/bin/activate # Activates your environment
$ python -m pip install numpy
$ python run.py
```

Doing so will gather all your dependencies in /path/to/env without messing up with your global setup.

Comment: In answer to your question, I get 
python -m pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
Beaker     1.11.0
Mako       1.1.2
Markdown   3.2.1
    MarkupSafe 1.1.1
    pip        20.1.1
    setuptools 46.4.0
    I don't think I installed any of these, not even pip, for which version numbers differ.

Comment: In response to your question, my system responded to  
python -m pip list with    
Package    Version.  
---------- -------  
Beaker     1.11.0.  
Mako       1.1.2.  
Markdown   3.2.1.  
MarkupSafe 1.1.1.   
pip        20.1.1.  
setuptools 46.4.0.  
I don't think I installed any  of these.

Comment: OK, just leave it there for now. I think some packages are used by macOS, but I'm not sure... 
For now, just work inside your virtualenv and you should be just fine